# Image upload direct to S3 with sign from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I looking for someone that can make a example of a image upload direct to S3 with jQuery-File-Upload or similar that supports IE8+. Both the client-side and server-side in node / express.  Designed with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)? It is node library for working with AWS. It is well documanted, [have a lot of code snippets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Create_a_New_Bucket_and_Object__createBucket__upload_) and helps to work with Amazon S3.